# Appending rows, if different, by matching keys in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

What should I use to append matching fields, matched by two keys, into the same row instead of being in separate rows? I'm somewhat familiar with the groupby() function, but I can't figure out what to use for strings or numbers (the answers on SO seem to be for integers only). When I try the aggregate function, I receive an error regarding 'SeriesGroupBy' not having an attribute 'IP Address' or 'Hostname', I'm still working with it to see if it's the solution.

I want to take this data:

```
host    ip           user 
nom1    10.41.3.2    Kelly 
nom1    10.41.3.3    Kate
nom2    10.5.5.5     Mary 
nom3    10.1.1.2     Joe
```

And turn it into this:

```
host    ip                     user 
nom1    10.41.3.2, 10.41.3.3   Kelly, Kate
nom2    10.5.5.5               Mary 
nom3    10.1.1.2               Joe
```

Here is my merge method: `final = pd.merge(a, b, on=["Computer Name", "IP Address", "User Name"], how='outer')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with a custom function to join the strings separated by a delimiter that gets applied to all the columns of the grouped object:

```
df.groupby('host', as_index=False).agg(lambda grp: ', '.join(grp))
```

[image]

Comment: And, with `as_index=False` in `groupby` call, if you'd want flat dataframe with `host` as column.

Comment: Thanks @NickilMaveli that did the trick. That's a nifty trick you used with Lambda, I'm not familiar with it but I think I see how it works. Thanks to you too, John (wouldn't let me correct my original comment).